# Python IRC Bot: Set variable from channel

Tags: python, variables, bots, irc

I'm working on a simple IRC bot that will pull data from a webpage for me.
In order for it to search for the data I need the bot to assign a variable and I've not yet figured out how to do that.

When I enter the following:

- !hc wb5od

I want to assign wb5od (or whatever might be there in it's place) and assign it to a variable called 'callsign'.

If I can figure out how to do that, I should be able to manage the rest of having it grab the data and print it to the screen.

EDIT

Below is how I am getting data from and printing it to the irc channel

```
    if data.find ( '!hc die' )!= -1:
        s.send("PRIVMSG %s %s \r\n" % (CHAN, "Well...... I never!"))
        s.send ( 'QUIT\r\n' )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if data.find ( '!hc call' )!= -1:
   #re1 = 'call(.*?)*'
    re1 = r"call\s\b(.*)\b"
    rg = re.compile(re1,re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
    m = rg.search(data)
    if m:
        cdata = m.group(1)
        #s.send("PRIVMSG %s %s \r\n" % (CHAN, cdata))
        s.send ("PRIVMSG %s %s \r\n" % (CHAN, 'Querying Radio Reference...'))
        url = "http://radioreference.com/apps/ham/callsign/%s" % cdata
        callsign_query = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        content = callsign_query.read()
        re2 = '<span style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;">(.*?)</span>'
        rg = re.compile(re2,re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
```